# how to filter data from array and apply conditions angular8

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular8

I am getting below sample data from api dynamically.

Can anyone suggest how to apply condition based on data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check values in array

```
if (this.tagSchemaDetails.schema_context.providers.indexOf('All') < 0) {
   request['schema_context'] = this.createConditionsData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your providers is array of string and you are just comparing that with string so in all cases it will validate the condition.

So you have to check the strings in the array and compare them with 'All' to properly check the condition. 
So your code should look like this:

```
if(!this.tabSchemaDetails.schema_context.providers.includes('All')){
     request['schema_context']=this.createConditionsData();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

as others have said here, you have to check values in the "providers" array. since you just need to check provider != 'All' you can simply check for the first element in the array as below.

```
if (this.tagSchemaDetails.schema_context.providers[0] !== 'All') {
        request['schema_context'] = this.createConditionsData();
    }
```